# Running a foreach loop with IF/ELSE using a MYSQLI while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

I'm generating a array using a foreach loop, but to check if the input is correct I'm checking it against a database, hence the While loop.

However, this code.. obviously ends up running everything twice.......

```
while($mp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mappings_selected)) {
foreach ($inputdata as $key => $val) {
    $value = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\r\n", "\v", "\t", "\0","\x"), " ", $val);
    $pos = substr($value,0, strpos($value, ' '));
    $fnc1 = $mp['function_1'];
    $fnc2 = $mp['function_2'];
    $rank_1 = $mp['rank_1'];
    $rank_2 = $mp['rank_2'];
    $rank_3 = $mp['rank_2'];
    $usergrp = $mp['user_group'];

    if (preg_match("/^(?=.*(?:\b$fnc1\b|\b$fnc2\b))(?=.*(?:\b$rank_1\b|\b$rank_2\b|\b$rank_3\b)).*$/", $val) ){
        $usergroup = ",,,,,,,,,,,".$coursegroup.$usergrp.",";
    } else  ......
```

My goal would be to run the foreach loop, then in each iteration check for matches against the database, without ALL the code running twice...

Any advice?

Comment: You would need to post the whole while loop at least.

Comment: that is the whole while loop, but I don't know where to start and/or end it.. The only thing the while loop is used for is the preg_match...

Comment: This is one complicated code, Your issue might not be how to solve your problem with the provided code, but it might be about finding a better approach to accomplish your task. Since I don't have the full picture here I would suggest you cache your results somewho & use the cached result to increase your performance (I assume that's why you asked this question), if you need actual help with your design ... please provide background info about what you are trying to accomplish and how you are doing it.